# Copy Unique Values from Filtered Range to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to copy the unique cell data from Column G on uldata to A2 of verdata and getting the following error.

"Run Time Error 1004: Database or Table Range is not Valid"

```
Set uldrange = u1data.Range("G1:G" & u1datalr)
uldrange.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="Car", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Boat"
uldata.Range("G2:G" & uldatalr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=verdata.Range("A2"), Unique:=True
```

I tried as well just using

```
Set uldrange = u1data.Range("G1:G" & u1datalr)
uldrange.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="Car", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Boat"
uldrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=verdata.Range("A2"), Unique:=True
```

and got an error of "Autofilter method of Range Class failed"

Help!!!

Comment: How did you define `uldata` and `verdata`?

Comment: Something like `uldrange.specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).copy verdata.Range("A2")` should work if you have defined things as you should have.

Comment: uldrange is defined as a range

verdata is defined as a worksheet

Comment: @RonRosenfeld `uldrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy verdata.Range("A2")` will copy ALL of the visible lines, but I am wanting to paste only unique values from Column G

Comment: Missed that. You can use the `Advanced Filter`, but you need to use it properly, You omitted the Criteria Range in your argument list (and have it set up properly); and there's no purpose in using both the AutoFilter and the Advanced Filter.  For example: `uldrange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange:=criteriaRange, copytorange:=vrdata.Range("A2"), Unique:=True`

Comment: In addition, although it does not seem necessary in my version of Excel, I recall that in previous versions, it was necessary to `Activate` the destination worksheet before using `AdvancedFilter` to copy to a particular worksheet.

Comment: If you don't mind to use scripting.dictionary, after you filter - please try : `dim arr as object:Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")`, next line : `for each cell in uldata.Range("G2:G" & uldatalr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible): arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1: Next` --> this will get only the unique value from "G2:G" & uldatalr to arr variable. Next line : `verdata.Range("A2").Resize(arr.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(arr.keys)` ---> this will put the items in arr to verdata starting from cell A2.